# How to fix not click when the fragment this open?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onitemclick

I have a Recycler View and when I click an item I open a fragment with information about that item.

Well I have the problem that even open the fragment, I can keep clicking to the other elements of the list.

As I fix, you can be?

The problema is there?

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(String.valueOf(fragment)).commit();

Comment: "As I fix, You can be?" ??? what?

Comment: please be specify with your question

Comment: Either set fragment layout as android:clickable="true" or set the view with recyclerview as another fragment and then call replace on check change events.

Comment: The oncliclable longer to false but I can just click, I mean when I open the fragment can click equal to the list without seeing her. As if on position.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity set flag isOpened. 
And set it true when you click the item of RecyclerView. Then when you click other items check:
if (!isOpened) {not allow to open fragment}

Comment: I mean I have to see if this open and if open not let you click?
But that in fragment.java in main.java or xml?

Comment: I think in main.java